# Paste as in replace mode

Tags: vim

I got used to indent my code in such way:

```
  asd          sthng
  asd someText sthng
```

I would like to paste something in the space in the first line. I would like to keep indention also.

Result of pasting:

```
  asd pstdText sthng
  asd someText sthng
```

Is there a way in VIM to paste a text in a way how replace mode (`R`) works?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can enter replace mode with `R` and then insert the contents of the register via `<C-R>"`.

Alternatively, if you select the amount of text that corresponds to the to-be-pasted text (or there's a motion that covers such), you can use my [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) to replace the selection with the register (without losing the register contents).